# synaptics touchpad not working properly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, synaptic, scrolling, scrollbar

I am new to Linux the first thing which is bothering me is I can't use scroll down on my touch pad I have to drag the scroll bar manually.
If anyone can help me 
its a synaptics touchpad